# confused of setting up a server in MERN project

Tags: node.js, express, server, backend

having been working on small projects and try to combine them into one big project now
but somehow found really really confused

in project A, I have written a backend with below code

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
```

and meanwhile in project B
I have written a backend of realtime chat app with socket.io as below shown

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const server = http.createServer(app);
```

should I only keep only one of them ?
my project A and B works separately
but when I tried to combine I cannot even go through postman

what are the differences between these 2 settings ??
since I wanna reuse the routes in project A
but all the routes starts with
router.get...
router.post...etc

how should I fix this
please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to assist you, I'll brainstorm a little below:

If I understand right, you are using different real-time communication packages which are Express and socket.io. This is likely to be the problem here, maybe you can try to instantiate Express routers as a middleware layers and let socket.io handle the main "router" functionality.

Comment: you're welcome, if you can't solve, let me know so after work I'll try it out